# Extract Environment Variables used in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

There's some way to extract all the environment variables that a script use?
I have some big scripts that use several environment variables to work properly.

But read all the code and manually copy all the environment variables "calls" that I find would be very boring and with a high change os miss a few of them!

There's some sort of script or plugin that does this kind of job?

And example would be:

```
teste.sh:
  if [ ! -z "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ] ; then
  export DOCKER_IMAGE_FULL_NAME="$REGISTRY_URL/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
  else
  export DOCKER_IMAGE_FULL_NAME="$REGISTRY_URL/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:pid$CI_PIPELINE_ID"
  fi


Variables Found:
$CI_COMMIT_TAG
$REGISTRY_URL
$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME
$CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

Comment: `env` is your friend.

Comment: Or `cat /proc/self/environ` for content in completely unambiguous (NUL-delimited) form.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That will show the entire environment, not just the ones that the script uses.

Comment: As is proper and correct, yes; if saving the environment to reproduce later, one should save the whole thing.

Comment: One can't tell which variables a script will use without running it, because scripts can run arbitrary, dynamic code. Indirect expansion exists. `eval` and moral equivalents exist.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy While that's true, most scripts don't. A static analysis is usually sufficient.

Comment: There are also a whole lot of variables that are used by the shell itself for configuration &c even if the script never explicitly references them.

Comment: Use a regular expression. If you assume the environment variables are all-uppercase, `\$[A-Z0-9_]+` should be good

Comment: @Barmar, ...consider for example that `PATH` isn't _explicitly_ referenced here, but its value will dramatically change how the script runs. And that's a very glaring example, but there are subtle ones too.

Comment: `SHELLOPTS`, `BASHOPTS`, etc etc etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This seems like they're trying to generate documentation of all the environment variables explicitly referenced.

Comment: And I continue to hold that assuming that only _explicit_ references matter is a bad idea. If you build your debugging tools to only store the things you know will matter in your logs, f/e, those logs will be meaningfully incomplete.

Comment: @FelipeVegini ...moving away from the argument towards the spirit of your question -- the Haskell library used by https://shellcheck.net/ can certainly do this, as shellcheck does in practice look for explicitly referenced variables (and determine whether/where they've been assigned).

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: The shell option from @Barmar was enough for my need! I adapted it to also include the environment variables within {} and it worked really well.  `\$[{A-Z0-9_}]+`

Comment: `some sort of script or plugin that does this kind of job?` How could it ever detect variables used in non-taken code paths? I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far from perfect, but you could use a regular expression to extract all variable expansions of the forms `$var`, `${VAR}`, `${Var-default}`, `${VAR:+alternative}` and others.

```
grep -io '\${\?[[:alnum:]_]\+[}:+-=?]\?' yourscript.sh | tr -d '{}:+-=?'
```

The equivalent extended grep call:

```
grep -ioE '\$\{?[[:alnum:]_]+[}:+-=?]?' yourscript.sh | tr -d '{}:+-=?'
```

First, everything that looks like a variable is grepped and then delimiters are removed from the output.